# Resize CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor and would like to resize the editor.  I am doing the following:

```
<head runat="server">

    <script src="../../../../../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../../../js/ckeditor_initialize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ResizeEditor() {
            var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('tbEditor');
            editor.resize('100', '800');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ResizeEditor();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox class="ckeditor" ID="tbEditor" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
```

But it does not seem to work.  I think I may be getting the CKEditor Instance incorrectly.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

I am using CKEditor 4 with .net 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can set size directly in the `CKEDITOR.replace` method:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'tbEditor', { width: 800, height: 100 } );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resize Ckeditor in the following way:-

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
editor.config.resize_dir = 'both';   //if you want to enable resizing, else use resize_enabled = false;
editor.config.height = 'your height';
editor.config.width = 'your width';
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to resize only one editor and not all editors on the page. This is how I did it in version 4.7.0

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceLoaded', function (e) {

     if (e.editor.name == 'html_name_of_your_DOM_element') {
        e.editor.resize(800, 350);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here don't work with replace, because I need destroy before and I understand you do not have to do this.

You can resize this way:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['tbEditor'];
if (editor) {
     editor.resize(100, 800);
}
```